# How to mongoimport from any location in cmd

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

So right now I'm using mongoose to work with MongoDB (learning). Something I tried to do was import a JSON array by using

`mongoimport --db mongo-testing --collection test  --drop --file data.json --jsonArray`

but it didn't work giving an error that `mongoimport` was not found. After looking around in StackOverflow, I found that you needed to run the command in the \bin\ folder where your mongo PATH variable points to. So I did just that.

`mongoimport --db mongo-testing --collection test  --drop --file /d/Node/mongo-test/data.json --jsonArray`

The command above I ran in the `\bin\` folder and pointed the file via an absolute path and it worked! However, I don't think that's the right way to do it.

Question: Is there a way I could run the command in `/d/Node/mongo-test/` file where my Node.js project is or do I need to go to the bin folder each time

**bin folder for mongo**

[image]

Comment: Hi @sarman. Which version of mongo you are using?

Comment: Add mongo to the [`PATH variable`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#add-mongodb-binaries-to-the-system-path) then you can access it from any directory

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: @wak786 yes i am. Have this in PATH: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin. I also included the bin folder contents above

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I did add mongo to path variable

Comment: @sarman By seeing your PATH it seems you are using mongo 4.4. But as far as i know from 4.4 version all database tools(mongoimport, mongoexport etc) are not part of bin folder. You have to install them separately. Did you put  them there manually?

Comment: @wak786 yeah i installed it by via msi download (not zip). Didn't work (same error), so I copied the files (not moving the originals) into the bin folder as you see above to get it working using the second-way outlined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** So I tried **downloading the zip file instead of the msi**. After downloading it, copy it into mongoDB path in ProgramFiles (beside Server is where i put it).

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.2.0\bin`

Add the above line into ur PATH variables (if you put it in the same spot).

Close all terminals and **if you are using VSC terminal, close the program and restart it.**

This worked for me! Hope it helps someone too